# Using PIL ImageTk.PhotoImage results in error "'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'"

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to the following code in python 3.7.3 with PIL version 6.2.1:

```
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic))
```

but it results in an error message like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/python/test/test10.py", line 12, in <module>
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(pic))
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3489, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
RuntimeError: Too early to create image
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x0000027A91FEB0D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\erica\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 124, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

I have tried different Pillow versions, tried inputting class instance as suggested from other posts, tried using `os.chdir(pic_dir)`. But they all don't work.

Comment: Not sure why what you're doing doesn't work. Try `render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.open(pic))` and `render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=pic)` (assuming `pic` is a filename).

Comment: Thank. Answer but I try both already that result the same error

Comment: When all else fails, try reinstalling PIL/Pillow.

Comment: Already try reinstall, with different version as well. But same error

Answer (score 5):

Using the [ImageTk module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html) depends on a Tkinter instance because [`ImageTk.PhotoImage`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) is designed to be "*used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object*".

From the Traceback, `PhotoImage` basically just calls Tkinter's PhotoImage constructor:

```
self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
```

then the [base class for `PhotoImage`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3989) checks for a running Tkinter instance:

```
def __init__(self, imgtype, name=None, cnf={}, master=None, **kw):
    self.name = None
    if not master:
        master = _default_root
        if not master:
            raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
```

and since it doesn't find one, it raises that "*Too early to create image*" error. Then in PIL, it just ignores that error ("*Exception ignored in:...*") so the rest of the creation of `PhotoImage` fails with the error you are getting.

To solve this, the Tkinter parts have to be properly initialized.

Try creating a Tkinter instance first:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.open("sample.jpg"))
```

Or use the generic [`Image`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html) module that does not depend on Tkinter.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I had ```file=image``` and that didn't work.

Comment: great this was the solution for me
``` To solve this, the Tkinter parts have to be properly initialized.

Try creating a Tkinter instance first: ```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("yourimage.png")) # photoimage attribute error .......
img = Label(self.root,image = self.img).place(x=0,y=0,relheight=1,relwidth=1)
#love man
```